# CAPL: display data of received message onto a GUI

Tags: capl, canoe

I am new to CANoe/CAPL.

I am trying to display the data of the received message onto a GUI.
This will be a message that is 64 bytes, so I would like multi-line support.
Thus far, all I have seen as an option for multi-line GUI box is the "CAPL Output View".

For instance, if I receive a message from 0x01333DDC, 00 00 10 AC DD;
I want 00 00 10 AC DD to be printed on the GUI input window.
I also want multi-line printing as the messages are 64 bytes.

I have tried:

1. Assign message.byte() to a system variable, then use PutValueToControl()
2. PutValueToControl(messageXxX)

In all cases, all 0 values are returned on the CAPL output view, although message received through trace window actually shows that there are non-zero values in the message data.

Thank you in advance for any comments/help,

Edit:
Below is my code.
This is done on a real CAN bus (not simulated) as there is an ECU connected that sends the message.
The message is configured to 64 bytes in size and named msg_DATA_REQ_REC.
It is stored in a system variable of int array 64 bytes named DATA_REQ_REC.

I am trying to output the message data content into a CAPL output view named Rx_DATA on a panel named "MONITOR_PANEL".
Also, an LED indicator (LED_REC) is set to blink when the message is received.

```
on message DATA_REQ_REC                //When when DATA_REQ is received from other ECU on CAN
{
  //store received message data into system variable DATA_REQ_REC
  for (i = 0; i < 64; i++)
  {
    @MONITOR_PANEL::DATA_REQ_REC[i] = msg_DATA_REQ_REC.byte(i);
  }
  putValueToControl("MONITOR_PANEL", "Rx_DATA", "\r \r");
  
  //If the first byte is empty
  if (@MONITOR_PANEL::DATA_REQ_REC[0] == 0x00)
  {
    //do nothing
  }else
  {
    //display all 64 bytes of data in DATA_REQ_REC
  for (i = 0; i < 64; i++)  
  {
   putValueToControl("MONITOR_PANEL", "Rx_DATA", @MONITOR_PANEL::DATA_REQ_REC[i]);
  }
    putValueToControl("MONITOR_PANEL", "Rx_DATA", "\r \r");*/
  }

//need to move LED activation into else statement if want to blink only for APDU_REQ with data
  @MONITOR_PANEL::LED_REC = 1;       //Turn on Data Indicator LED
  setTimer(Timer_LED_REC, 200);  //set LED timer  
}

on timer Timer_LED_REC
{
 @MONITOR_PANEL::LED_REC = 0;        //Turn off Data Indicator LED
}
```

Comment: There is no `message.byte()` that takes no parameter, nor a `PutValueToControl(...)` with that signature. Please show your code.

Comment: @MSpiller, thank you for the comment. I added my code to the original post as "edit" since it exceeds character limits for a "comment".

Comment: What is the value of property `Output mode` of your control?

Comment: @MSpiller, the output mode is set to "Append". The message will be coming through repeatedly. I want to be able to see all receiving of this particular message when it has data content (when 1st byte is a non-zero value) for the entire session.

Comment: That all looks good. Which output do you get in the control? Nothing at all?

Comment: @MSpiller, thank you for the check.
After hours of reviewing, I discovered that I initialized DATA_REQ_REC and DATA_REC as system variables. Both were initialized with the value 0. The message data was being assigned to DATA_REC while DATA_REQ_REC was being displayed. The code works now. Thank you.
The problem remains of data value being in HEX and being displayed on CAPL input view as DEC remains, but I have found a couple of posts that may work as solutions (need to test them).